# SQL for multiple rows with unique values from multiple unique values

Tags: sql

I have the following update SQL that works for a single row.

```
UPDATE myshcema.my_table
SET emp_id = '000987654321'
WHERE cust_id = '000123456789';
```

But I have over 6500 unique cust_ids that = 6500 unique emp_id.  I would like to update all of my emp_id column with the corresponding cust_id in the cust_id coulmn.  This table has other information in it but I'm missing about 5000 emp_id.  I have a .csv that has the cust_id, emp_id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

From the basic information you've provided, it sounds like you need to use a from statement in your update. First you need to load that CSV into a table on your DB.

This statement can be different based on what db you're using, but you should get the gist of it

```
UPDATE my_table tbl
SET emp_id = csv.emp_id
FROM your_new_csv_table csv
WHERE tbl.cust_id = csv.cust_id;
```

Comment: That's non-standard SQL. Please at least mention for which DBMS product this works.

Comment: I don't know what you think is standard SQL, this will work in almost every database that allows updates with a from clause. If you read the question the author didn't supply a database so I kept it generic. Stack overflow is not here to write code for you.

Comment: "standard SQL" is what the ANSI SQL standard defines. And there, FROM is not allowed in an UPDATE clause. "*so I kept it generic*" - no you didn't as that isn't generic (aka "standard") SQL. It's DBMS specific e.g. it won't work at all in Oracle, DB2 or Firebird. And would not work in SQL Server as that requires a different syntax when using a FROM clause for an UPDATE statement